# Where is the id being incremented?

Tags: javascript, html

First off i'm new to web stuff(html, javascript, ajax etc..) was just wondering where is the `id incrementing`  :

```
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            drawLabels(labels[i].id, labels[i].xMin, labels[i].xMax, labels[i].yMin, labels[i].yMax);
        }
```

but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `id` is not incremented. What is being incremented is the loop counter variable `i`...

Comment: Why do you think the `id` is incremented.

Comment: Because when i draw a new object it has the id of the previous +1 so it must be incrementing it somehow unless i'm missing something

Comment: The code you've shown only **reads** the `id` property of a number of objects. You would have to look at the code which creates those objects to determine how it was being set to different values in the first place.

Comment: @Jess — (a) You need to put an [mcve] in the question itself. (b) That code doesn't include the code which generates the data. It has a template placeholder where it gets inserted by some other code.

Answer (score 2):

The *id* isn't incrementing, the `i` variable is being incremented (in the third expression of the `for`, `i++`), and then the `id` is being read from `labels[i].id`, so each time the loop body runs, that's a *different* object (`labels[i]`). Presumably those different objects have different `id`s.

Comment: Well then back to my question, how is the id being incremented ?

Comment: @Jess: Again: It isn't, in the code in the question. It's a *different* `id` in each loop, because `labels[i]` is a different object.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` property is not being incremented. Perhaps the `labels` array comes from the database and each label has its own `id` value coming from the database.

The index `i` is incremented when you do `i++`, hence iterating the labels using `labels[i]`.

Comment: Yes i still don't understand how we're adding id values there.

Comment: @Jess They are already added in the `labels` array. Image that the `labels` array looks like this: `[{ id: 0, some: "data" }, { id: 1, some: "data" }, { id: 42, some: "data" }]`

Comment: which line if i may ask

Comment: @Jess It seems they come [from the config](https://github.com/sgp715/simple_image_annotator/blob/f7ba8e9e22002a2cce0047b3f390787c2b837c05/app.py#L21).